Disable Drag and Drop movements of entries
In our current project, we see the risk of editors unintentionally moving entries in structures using drag and drop.
Does anyone know if it is possible

to deactivate drag'n'drop in general,
to activate drag'n'drop only when required
or to confirm moves via modal window

Any ideas on that?

None of these are currently possible, as far as I know.
A quick search reveals this abandoned plugin, this feature request and, lo and behold, a feature request created by you in 2022.
I’d say that until you hear something concrete back from Pixel & Tonic about it, your best bet is to remove the draggable handles using some injected JavaScript.

Haha my own request :-) my memories are coming back
